# using docker.build on a windows slave

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins

Using a Jenkinsfile, I try to build a container and push it to the registry.
When getting to the stage of running docker.build an error occurred "Cannot run program "nohup" : CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified".

When switching the docker.build to 'bat "docker build ."' the stage passes in the pipeline and on the docker is created on the slave machine.
The snippet that I'm running (the commented line is the one that works for me)

```
stage('Build image') {
        steps {
        script {
                //bat "docker build . -t bmanager"
                def app = docker.build("bmanager", ".")
        }
        }
    }
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Show us the content of docker.build then

Comment: @Aserre edited my question